# Translating "No, she does not want a different one" from duolingo

Tags: word-order

I am trying to translate the following sentence

> No, she does not want a different one.

My first intuition as an English speaker is

> Nein, sie will nicht anderes einen

Basically I translate word for word except I put the adverb `nicht` after the verb.

However the correct answer given in duolingo is

> Nein einen anderen will sie nicht

My question is that is my answer also correct? Can you switch the object order with subject because the ending of the noun already signals the object (via accusative case)? And why is `will sie nicht` correct instead of `will nicht sie` ?

Comment: Does duolingo not provide more context? Another flight, another table in the restaurant, another guy,... may ask for different precise translations, even if your final example is a quite generic one apart from the missing comma: *Nein, *

Comment: For a qualified answer, context is necessary. What is this sentence about? Somebody in a shop insisting on a specific product, not a surrogate? A good translates will take into account the situation where this sentence is used.

Answer (score 2):

German does not have SVO word worder. It's V2 in declarative clauses and SOV in dependent clauses. V2 includes SVO, but it's not limited to that.

You may use OVS word order in declarative clauses whenever you wish. It does not depend on the case being distinguishable. If there's ambiguity, its up to you to add information to make things clear — or leave them unclear by purpose. It doesn't have to be an accusative object either.

> Markus antwortete ich: „Dann eben nicht!“

Here, *Markus* is an unmarked leading dative object. It's clear from context (*ich* is nominative) who's the subject.

> Der Lüge verdächtige ich dich!

Thats a leading genitive object, verb second, subject, accusative object.

> Ein Hund ist er!

That's a leading *Prädikativ* ("nominative object"), the copula *sein*, and the subject.

---

About the *nicht*, the closest to English you can get is as follows.

*No, she does not want a different one.*

> Nein, **sie** will einen anderen *nicht*.
>
> Nein, **einen anderen** will sie *nicht*.

These are both possible but the first one sounds unnatural if **sie** isn't emphasized in speech. Remember the rule about word ordering and emphasis? **The first item gets the most emphasis, the last second most**. The last is *nicht*. But the thing you want to express isn't *sie–nicht* but *einen anderen–nicht*. That's why *einen anderen* should be emphasized and therefore, has to lead the clause.

> Nein, **einen anderen** will *nicht sie*.

This is also possible but it negates *sie* instead of the whole clause. People would ask "Then, who wants a different one, if not she?"

*Nicht* negates the following item. If it's at the end of a clause, it negates the whole clause.

If you want to put it plain, without special emphasis, use the pronoun *kein*. It's especially made for that purpose.

> Nein, **sie** will *keinen anderen*.
>
> Nein, **keinen anderen** will *sie*.

Here, the emphasis is split almost equally *sie—keinen anderen*, with only a slight advantage on *sie* resp. *keinen anderen*.

Comment: You could add that all this assumes that the grammatical gender of the other is male.

Comment: I have just taken this as given from the question. But it was the Duolingo translation, so yes, one has to honor the gender. I frown a bit because it makes the answer harder to read to include all genders.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your questions with some examples. The English expression `a different one` does not work without the `one` at the end, so it is fixed and could be translated to `ein Anderer`. 
A more literal translation would be: `Nein, sie möchte keinen Anderen.` or `Nein, einen Anderen möchte sie nicht.` `einen` is the article and it always has the position in front of the noun. Therefore your translation does not work in German. Moreover `anderes` is neuter, which is rather unlikly, if we assume that she wants another man. You could translate `Nein, sie will nicht einen Anderen.` More fluently is to pull together `will nicht einen` to `will keinen`. 
To your last point: Grammaticaly correct, but the emphasis differs. If you put `sie` at the end you put strong emphasis on it, because it is not the usual order in the sentence. As in English: `No, a different one she does not want.`